# onStateConflict without conflict

Tags: android, google-play-services

I am having problems with the AppStateClient from google play services. When i let the code below run on only one device I get into onStateLoaded as expected - but when another device is involved I get conflicts all the time without there being a conflict in the data

```
    @Override
    public void onSignInSucceeded() {
        Log.i("", "StatCount" + playHelper.getAppStateClient().getMaxNumKeys());
        playHelper.getAppStateClient().updateState(0, "test".getBytes());
        playHelper.getAppStateClient().loadState(new OnStateLoadedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onStateLoaded(int i, int i2, byte[] bytes) {
                Log.i("AppStateTest","load {" +  new String(bytes) +"}");
            }

            @Override
            public void onStateConflict(int i, String s, byte[] bytes, byte[] bytes2) {
                Log.i("AppStateTest","conflict " + new String(bytes) +" <> " + new String(bytes2));
            }
        },0);
    }
```

output:

```
I/AppStateTest( 4173): conflict test <> test
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working as intended. A conflict doesn't mean that the **data** is different. The data itself is *not* taken into account when determining a conflict. What determines is a conflict is that another device wrote to the data since this device has last read it. Consider this:

1. Device A reads "Foo"
2. Device B reads "Foo"
3. Device A writes "Foo"
4. Device B writes "Foo"

In this case, even though the data is the same, Device B would get a conflict (which would be signaled when loading the data any time after step 4). Not because the data is different but because **a write from another source happened since the data was last read**.

If, from the point of view of your app's logic, this is not considered a conflict, then simply resolve it by calling resolveConflict.